# string variable as latex in pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, latex

It is possible to have Latex formatting in pyplot diagrams, i.e. for title, labels etc.

```
#some dummy code
plt.plot(x,y,label = r"$a < \gamma$")
```

It is generated by adding an r before the actual latex string.
Now, pyplot accepts variables as inputs for strings, i.e.

```
#some dummy code
foo = "some fancy label"
plt.plot(x,y, label = foo)
```

I would like to combine the two worlds, however the only answer I found on SO is for Julia.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The example would look like:

```
foo = r"some fancy label and $a < \gamma$"
plt.plot(x,y, label = foo)
```

The point of adding an `r` is that it makes the string a [raw string (literal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l). This is necessary because `\` is no valid string literal. However, `\` can be escaped by another `\`, such that the following is valid as well

```
foo = "some fancy label and $a < \\gamma$"
plt.plot(x,y, label = foo)
```

Note that there is no `r` in front of the string.

Also note that the dollar signs `$` are not actually invoking latex but what is called [MathText](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html). In order to get true latex rendering you would need to have a working latex installation and invoke the `usetex=True` parameter;  details [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-tutorial).

Comment: Do you know how to combine raw strings with variable substitution? For example, how to make `foo = r"some fancy label and $ {myvar} < \gamma$"` to get the `myvar` value in place?